# High response time for opening an tranasactionn

Tags: java, spring

We are using below code to get transation however the last time is taking too much time (some time more then 10 minute) in production environment where we will have multiple requets coming for same service . Can some one please provide possible cause of this behavior .

```
final DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
transStatus = txManager.getTransaction(def);
```

txManager is of type DataSourceTransactionManager and we are using DB2 database with WebSphere server 6.1 .

Comment: Did you check the size of the connection pool, what did it turn out to be?

Comment: max number of connection is 50 which should be enough to handle the load as we have another JVM  and same count worked fine there .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a connection pool? According to the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html), this transaction manager requires one.

You could be hitting the connection pool maximum limit in production, try increasing it.

Comment: yes , We are using connection pool . however max number of connection is 50 which should be enough to handle the load as we have another JVM  and same count worked fine there .

Comment: did you check with the DBAs to see if there many connections being opened? If they see 50 coming from where you run the JVM, you will know the limit is reached, meaning either too many simultaneous requests or connections leaked.Post here what the DB2 DBAs and the Websphere admins had to say about this, and any stacktraces you have (if too long post them on pastebin), right now there is too litle information to be able to see what is going on. Are there profiling tools available connected to that machine, like visualvm?